# 9v battery voltage drop and regain its voltage

Tags: batteries

as a part of my project , i have to develop +5v from an 9v carbon-zinc battery with 7805 regulator.it is given to microcontroller and some other circuitries .it consumes nearly 40ma. but,the problem is that " battery voltage drop fastly to less than 6v for continuous usage,nearly 20 minutes".then 7805 wont work and entire system will shut down. after,removing the battery,battery voltage increases from 6v to 8.5v and again performs well for next 20 minutes. i would like to use at least 1 hour continuously,without effecting performance.can you suggest a proper solution?

Comment: Have you tried an alkaline battery? That should easily work for an hour if your 40 mA figure is accurate.

Comment: Are you certain about the 40mA number? How are you measuring the current? I don't know what you mean by "lcd", but it's not unusual for LCD screens to consume far more than 40mA by themselves.

Comment: i am using carbon-zinc battery.can i use alkaline battery,for solving the problem?

Comment: i have used 9v battery directly to 7805 for grnerating +5v.inverter circuitry was made up with lt1054 for -5v by same battery and consume less current 35ma instead of 160ma .so i am happy now.the only problem,remaining is that voltage drop of battery for continuous use,nearly 20 minutes.can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most batteries under load will drop their voltage and the voltage will then go back up when the load is removed.  The voltage will drop especially quickly if the load is high or the battery is close to being dead.

So you likely have one or both of the following:

1) Your load is way higher than 42 mA

2) You are using a battery that is already exhausted or perhaps you are using a carbon zinc battery or "heavy duty" battery?  They only have a capacity of about 50 mAh!  Even Duracell 9 volt only have approx 300 mAh, and some energizer are closer to 450 mAh.

As mentioned in another answer, using a battery holder with 6 AA batteries with last a lot longer as their capacity would be in the 2000+ mAh range.

Comment: i am using carbon-zinc battery.can i use alkaline battery,for solving the problem?

Comment: An alkaline will provide around 8-9x the capacity as the carbon zinc for a 9 volt. So assuming that your load is only 42 mA, a brand new energizer lithium 9v should give you close to 10 hours on run time.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

First of all - don't try to use a 9V battery.

A quick and easy solution is to head to your nearest electronics supply shop and purchase a battery holder that holds 6 pieces of "AA" cells.  These are often available with the same connector that a 9V battery has and it will connect exactly the same way as the 9V battery.

Comment: I think this answer would be more helpful if you elaborated on why 6 AA batteries are better than a single 9V battery.

Comment: Maybe if the OP only needs 5V for everything (ref the 7805), could he use four AA's and a better LDO or maybe even two AA's and a boost?